# How to set default value for property in model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have `RegisterModel` and i need to set default value for `SelectCountryID` and in controller pass that value but when i do like this i get an error :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public RegisterModel()
    {
        SelectCountryID=1;
    }

    public int SelectCountryID {get;set;} 
}
```

Controller:

```
int test = Model.Register.SelectCountryID;
```

EDIT:

```
IndexPageModel model = new IndexPageModel();
model.Register = new RegisterModel
            {
                int test = model.Register.SelectCountryId,
                Country = new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name"),
                WebTypeOfLicense = new SelectList(CommonDbService.GetAllLicense(), "Id", "Name"),
                Region = new SelectList(manager.GetRegions(model.Register.SelectCountryId), "Id", "Name"),


            };
```

Comment: You need to instantiate the object first...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not Understanding Object Instantiation in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888514/not-understanding-object-instantiation-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you instantiate your model.

```
model.Register = new RegisterModel{...}
```

This will execute what is in between the `{}` before calling the constructor. Also, you cannot define new variables within the braces like

```
{int test = model.Register.SelectCountryId,...}
```

In the controller, you need to create a new instance of the model like

```
RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
int test = model.SelectCountryID;
```

Comment: i create new instance its not that

Comment: @None, can you show more of your code? Which line does the error occur at? in the controller or in the class itself?

Answer (score 3):

you an use system.ComponentModel.DefaultValue attribute

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(0)]
public int SelectCountryID { get; set; }
```